# CSS cross browser image aligning issue

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, cross-browser

I am working on Ken university website, and i am getting issue of cross browser.

In IE 8 it is not showing properly.
But in firefox and chrome it works fine.

it is the image with the textbox which i am trying to fix..

Here is the Demo Page.
http://safijustonline.com/Forms/Student/StudentRegistration.aspx

please check it in both IE and firefox..

How to solve this cross-browser image alignment issue?

login details:

username = alinisar@ken.com
pass =123

---

update:

I have also added reset.css file in my theme.

generated HTML of my code:

```
<div id="CPH_Content_TabContainerStudentRegistration_TabPanelMain_Cmb_Shift" class="WindowsStyle" style="display:inline-block;">
<table id="CPH_Content_TabContainerStudentRegistration_TabPanelMain_Cmb_Shift_Cmb_Shift_Table" class="ajax__combobox_inputcontainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;display:inline-block;position:relative;top:5px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer">
<td class="ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer">
<button id="CPH_Content_TabContainerStudentRegistration_TabPanelMain_Cmb_Shift_Cmb_Shift_Button" type="button" style="height: 25px; width: 25px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; visibility: visible;"></button>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<ul id="CPH_Content_TabContainerStudentRegistration_TabPanelMain_Cmb_Shift_Cmb_Shift_OptionList" class="ajax__combobox_itemlist" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; z-index: 10000; overflow: hidden; width: 215px; position: absolute; height: 30px;">
<li>Morning</li>
<li>Evening</li>
</ul>
<input id="CPH_Content_TabContainerStudentRegistration_TabPanelMain_Cmb_Shift_Cmb_Shift_HiddenField" type="hidden" value="0" name="ctl00$CPH_Content$TabContainerStudentRegistration$TabPanelMain$Cmb_Shift$Cmb_Shift_HiddenField">
</div>
```

the css of my button and image:

```
.WindowsStyle .ajax__combobox_inputcontainer .ajax__combobox_buttoncontainer button {
    background-image: url("Images/windows-arrow.gif");
    background-position: left top;
    border: 0 none;
    height: 22px;
    margin: -10px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 22px;
}
```

Image on top of button.
[image]

Comment: It would be more easy to answer if you create a fiddle of relevant lines of code

Comment: could u tell us where exactly the image is?

Comment: trying using this css: it resets everything to default. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: @Sowmya
Ok. Let me add some CSS and HTML code too in my question for detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below meta tags in the Head  section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```

Remember the meta tag that is on top will be given first preference

Answer (score 0):

Add this and try

```
    .ajax__combobox_textboxcontainer{
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

I tested in IE8. It works

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uagA3/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is simple: Just add `display: block` to those elements style.
It have solve the problem on IE 10.

Element which is not displayed `block` don't use: `padding` and `margin`.
And my advice, try to use classes insted of inline style codding.

Answer (score 0):

did you try position:relative; or position:absolute;